# R.java file is not generated

Tags: android

I'm new to Android development. I listen Eclipse is better for beginners. So i downloaded and installed in my laptop, Setup also successfully done. My problem is that errors while run the project because R.java file is not generated. Please help me.

Comment: Voted to close , Duplicate

Comment: You can learn Android development on Android studio also there are lot of tutorials out there, use android studio.

Comment: R.java usually doesnt generate if you have an error in one of your xmls somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

check for other errors in your code. also check the uses of java package in .xml files (e.g. AndroidManifest.xml and layout files)